# Why doesn't kerl support HiPe for Linux?

Tags: erlang

[On the kerl page](https://github.com/kerl/kerl) it mentions that HiPe is not used for Linux because of otp_build (but I am assuming by implication it is okay for Mac OS). Why is that?

```
(Note that kerl uses the otp_build script internally, and ./otp_build configure disables HiPE on linux)
```